# How do I view a pdf file name present on my storage on a textView? java, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to append pdf file names on a textView

This is the function i am using

```
 public void Search_Dir(File dir) {
        String pdfPattern = ".pdf";

        textView.setText("");

        File FileList[] = dir.listFiles();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+FileList.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (FileList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < FileList.length; i++) {

                textView.append(FileList[i]+"\n");

                if (FileList[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Search_Dir(FileList[i]);
                } else {
                    if (FileList[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)){
                        //here you have that file.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the names of all the files other than pdf files don't know why though

function call

```
    Search_Dir(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
```

Comment: could you be a bit more precise about what is the error you are facing and what you expect

Comment: I am only getting the file name of files other than .pdf 
So basically in .dir.listfiles(); the list which I get does not include pdf files and i want pdf files in that list
@SambhavKhandelwal

Comment: That can happen only on an Android 11+ device for files not belonging to your app.